# Getting face normals from a mesh using Python is giving random vertices

Tags: python, mesh

I'm trying to get the face normal of a simple wall. When I run this in the script editor I always get the correct answer. However once it was extended into the script (as addon code) I started getting random answers for the face normal.

The mesh only has one face (with a solidify modifier). As seen in the output below, it's always using the same object/mesh when obtaining the face. Obviously something is changing in the way the mesh is called, but I have no idea what that may be.

```
    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    me = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    face = bm.faces[0]  
    norm = face.normal
```

[image]

```
obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -3916630420049055726017961787392.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -nan, -nan)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (75514781576491103645851451392.0000, 73154155242148890718019301769478144.0000, 2484523484973937897303441408.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -nan, -nan)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -4144592121687598083661019217920.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -392842560703958075921827627008.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000)>


obj -->  <bpy_struct, Object("2")>
me -->  <bpy_struct, Mesh("2.027")>
norm -->  <Vector (0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)>
qrot -->  <Quaternion (w=0.7071, x=-0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.7071)>
```

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.normal_update

Comment: So the mesh normals need to be updated each time prior to get the vector? There's not much info around this, so hard to know why this step would be required. I did find the alternate way to obtain the normal vector using (obj.data.polygons[0].normal) without having to get the meshes. This method provded consistent results.